# Validating captcha (in a repeater)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've created a web form programmatically using asp.net repeater, where one of the items/fields is an MSCaptcha control. On postback, I would like to validate the captcha. Been struggling to access it since the captcha field/control is inside the Repeater and this.FindControl("captchaid") returns null. Any ideas?

Also, I am able to access all the form values including captcha text through Request.Form["field id"]. What would be nice is to be able to actually validate the captcha and not just capture the value.

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: Yes I tried that... trying button.Parent.FindControl("captchaid"); results in null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using this.FindControl (as stated) you will search for controls in the current page or usercontrol, not in the repeater item. You will need to loop through the repeater items and perform the FindControl on the RepeaterItem instance until you find your captcha control. (Or google to find an implementation of FindControl that is recursive, though I would say this is probably less optimal).